# Can I save SSJS Variables in the Client?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, ssjs, cloudpage

I was wondering if I can save data from an SSJS function in the client to use in JS scripts that run on the client-side after page load. For example, get value from ampscript, then set that value as a variable in an SSJS script like below, then access that variable on the client.

```
%%[
set @name = Lookup ('Leads', 'name', 'id', _subscriberKey)
]%%
 <script runat=server language="JavaScript">
   Platform.Load("core", "1.1.1");
   var name = Variable.GetValue("@name");
   Variable.SetValue("@name_ssjs", name);
 </script>
```

Is there a way I can access that variable with a normal client-side script? I have seen the use of AJAX so that SSJS can access a client-side variable. But I have not seen anything that explains how the client can access SSJS variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is most certainly possible! To accomplish this, you would output your Server-side variables the same as you would in HTML - via inline declarations or using `Output()` (AMPScript) or `Write()` (SSJS).

When using **SSJS** you canuse the inline declaration of `<ctrl:var name="myVar" />`(see **[my blog post here](https://gortonington.com/sfmc-ssjs-2-overview/)** for some more detailed information on the capabilities of this) to push this variable into your existing Client-side JS.

Example:

```js
<script runat=server>
var myVar = "Hello";
</script>
<script>
console.log('<ctrl:var name="myVar" />');
</script>
```

The other option in **SSJS** is to write your Client-side JS code through a `Write()`. This would have it 'hard coded' into the response given to the requesting browser.

Example:

```js
<script runat=server>
var myVar = "Hello";
Platform.Response.Write("<script>console.log(" + myVar + ");</script>")
</script>
```

---

For **AMPScript**, you could use an [**inline declaration**](https://ampscript.guide/inline-ampscript/) of `%%=v(@myVar)=%%` to push your Server-side variable into Client-side JS. This would add it into an existing script written outside your Server-side code.

```
%%[
SET @myVar = "Hello"
]%%
<script>
console.log('%%=v(@myVar)=%%');
</script>
```

But, if you would rather handle the building of your code at the server level via **AMPScript**, you can use `Output()` combined with a `CONCAT()` to create the script same as a `Write()` in SSJS.

Example:

```
%%[
SET @myVar = "Hello"
OUTPUT(CONCAT("<script>console.log(",@myVar,");</script>"))
]%%
```

**IMPORTANT NOTE**: Be aware this will move that info to the 'front-end' which **can be read by anyone** that is looking at the source code, so **no private or secure info should be passed** from Server-Side to Client-side.

Comment: Disregard my previous comment. Your sentence structure is a bit weird, I think, but still correct.

Comment: Yeah i might edit it tomorrow to be a bit more coherent. I was typing it on my phone waiting to pick up deli meat so I was a bit distracted